# how to make game display as portrait mode inside landscape mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to make game display as portrait mode inside landscape mode in unity [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJvpL.jpg)?

Answer (score 0):

The configurations for aspect ratio and orientation can be found in the Player settings.

`Edit` > `Project Settings` > `Player`

For **Android** and **iOS**, modify the value of `Default Orientation` in the `Resolution and Presentation` section.

Available settings:
`Portrait`, `Portrait Upside Down`, `Landscape Left`, `Landscape Right`, `Auto Rotation`